# why i can't catch java.net.SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception, socket-timeout-exception

I have a Simple Multithread Server, the code of Threads looks like this:

```
public void run(){

 while(Ecoute()){

     str=LireTrame(this.socClient);//read text byte by byte 

    //some code here

    Dormir(500);//Sleep for 500ms  
   }     


}
```

I'd like to create a timeout of 3 minutes, if a client socket does not send a message in 3 minutes, the thread must be closed...

so I try that:

```
 public void run(){

        try {
        socClient.setSoTimeout(180000);//timeout for 3 min...
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(tache.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


 while(Ecoute()){

     try{
      str=LireTrame(this.socClient);//read text byte by byte 
    }
    catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException ex){
     log.append("timeout exception has benn catched \n") ;
     break;//break the while
   } 

    //some code here

    Dormir(500);//Sleep for 500ms  
   }     


}
```

the problem is that netbeans display an error message:
[image]

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

I tried this with SocketException but same result..

why i can't catch them ?

**UPDATE**: based on responses from thinksteep and mprabhat, I added th throw in LireTrame(..) but still i can't catch the Exception:

```
 public  String LireTrame(Socket socClient) throws java.net.SocketTimeoutException{
 int c = 0;
  String Nmea="";
boolean finL=true;
 do{
            try {
                c=socClient.getInputStream().read();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(tache.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    char ch=(char)c;

    Nmea=Nmea+ch;
    if(ch==';')
        finL=false;

  }while(finL);
 return Nmea;
 }



mai 11, 2012 8:04:02 PM Daemon.tache LireTrame
Grave: null
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
    at Daemon.tache.LireTrame(tache.java:232)
    at Daemon.tache.run(tache.java:87)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

are there any ideas to make this otherwise?

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea the Java standard library had translated versions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LireTrame(this.socClient);//read text byte by byte
```

should throw SocketTimeOutException. You didn't post code for this method, but I am assuming it is not throwing SocketTimeOutException which is why netbeans highlighting.

Comment: Post LireTram method. If any code you don't want to showup, remove it, but post the method content. It is clear from exception that LireTrame method failing, but not sure whether it has anyother try/catch

Comment: You are catching the error and logging but not throwing. add throw ex; When you are trying to catch SocketTimeOutException I would add same catch block in LireTrame also and rethrow instead of just using IOException, IOException is more generic

Comment: try {
           c=socClient.getInputStream().read();

            }catch (SocketTimeoutException socketEx) {
                throw socketEx;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                
            }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11168/discussion-between-smarty-twiti-and-thinksteep)

Answer (score 0):

[SocketTimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) is a [checked exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions) so before you can catch it you should throw that exception.

So

```
=LireTrame(this.socClient);//read text byte by byte
```

should throw `SocketTimeoutException` before you can catch it.

You are just logging the exception but not rethrowing it

After this line

```
Logger.getLogger(tache.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

add this line too

```
 throw SocketTimeoutException('SocketTimeOutException');
```

Comment: You should rethrow the exception so that caller will be informed, edited my post

Comment: are you getting compile time exception ? I edited my post to so as to send exception back to inform, in case you are getting compile error, do a clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I would declare `LireTrame()` to throw `IOException` and remove the internal try/catch altogether. It's poorly structured code as it is.

Answer (score -1):

This is admittedly a shot in the dark. I do not use netbeans, I do use eclipse. In eclipse, sometimes JDT compiler gets out of sync with reality. Doing a clean build of the project fixes things up.

I think in your case, it is netbeans that is acting. If you do commandline invocation of javac, do you get that error. If not, doing a clean inside netbeans will very likely fix the problem.